# Why my orderby method in linq does not work?

Tags: linq

I want to query distinct state names in a datatable called `ZipTable`, and use alpha-beta order to list the state name, but it does not work. Did I miss something?

```
public List<String> GetAllStates()
{
    ZipTableDataContext dc = new ZipTableDataContext(_connString);
    List<String> query = (from z in dc.ZipTables
                          orderby z.State
                          select z.State).Distinct().ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: this line "orderby z.State" does not work. Still in it's original sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `Distinct()` will undo your ordering, since it does not preserve the input sequence order.  You need to perform your `OrderBy` after the `Distinct()` call:

```
List<String> query = dc.ZipTables.Select(z => z.State)
                       .Distinct()
                       .OrderBy(s => s)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't work Reed, the table has multiple columns, not just State column.

Comment: @Steven Zack: Edited to correct... This should work now.  (Sorry about that - had misread the original slightly)